# Is there a way to automatically include multiple remotes when cloning a Git repository?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have a git repo that makes use of a few different remote urls. Is there a way I can set things so that these remotes are included in a clone of the repo. As it stands, every time I clone the repo, the clone includes only the standard remote reference pointing to origin.

If I can't get the master (i.e. upstream) repo to store and distribute these remote links, is there any handy way that I can get them to set after cloning that is commonly used. I'd think we could write a hook for this, but there doesn't appear to be a 'clone hook'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use GNU Awk to Append Additional Remotes

There is (unfortunately) no post-clone hook, but you can certainly append more than one URL to each remote. For example, on a freshly-clone repository, the following will add two additional URLs to *origin*:

```
awk '/url =/ {
         print;
         print "\turl = http://1st.example.com/foo.git";
         print "\turl = http://2nd.example.com/bar.git";
         next;
     };
     { print }' .git/config | tee .git/config
```

This will enable you to push all three URLs in sequence when you `git push origin`. You can adjust the pattern and print statements to suit if your needs are more complex.

Comment: That's helpful, but it's unfortunate that it adds a step to installation by others. My biggest concern is that it requires users to actually read the README so they know to run the script after cloning.... I guess that's just a limitation in git that I'll need to accept